# How do I vertically overlap divs if I'm sizing them using height percentages?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm using Bootstrap 5.0.0 Beta 2. I have a stack of image wrappers that occupy 100% of the height of the parent container in order to maintain relative heights/sizes. Each of the first wrapper class, `.piePipe-wrapper`, is set to be 14.93% of the total height, `.piePipe-wrapper.lastPipe` occupies 21.68%, and `.piePipe.piePipe-check` takes up 18.57% of the overall ratio. The images all have `object-fit: contain` on them.

Screenshot of layout:

[image: Screenshot of layout]

However, I'd like to stagger them a bit so they overlap and save some room (especially on smaller devices), and also add some padding between the last pipe and the second to last pipe. I've tried negative margins, transformY, a negative top value, and a few other things to no prevail. What am I missing?

Not sure if Bootstrap will run within StackOverflow, so [here's a link to my codepen](https://codepen.io/pixelbakery/pen/poNmGWb).

**HTML:**

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<section class="container-fluid py-3">
  <div class="container h-100 piePipe-container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
    <div class="piePipe-wrapper ">
      <img src="https://portfoliowaterfall.pbds.dev/assets/img/pieFirst.svg" class="piePipe" alt="First Pipe"/>
    </div>
    <div class="position-relative piePipe-wrapper">
      <img src="https://portfoliowaterfall.pbds.dev/assets/img/pieSecond.svg" class="piePipe" alt="Second Pipe"/>
    </div>
    <div class="piePipe-wrapper">
      <img src="https://portfoliowaterfall.pbds.dev/assets/img/pieThird.svg" class="piePipe" alt="Third Pipe"/>
    </div>
    <div class="piePipe-wrapper">
      <img src="https://portfoliowaterfall.pbds.dev/assets/img/pieFourth.svg" class="piePipe" alt="Fourth Pipe"/>
    </div>
    <div class="piePipe-wrapper piePipe-lastPipe d-flex justify">
      <img src="https://portfoliowaterfall.pbds.dev/assets/img/pieFifth.svg" class="piePipe" alt="Last Pipe"/>
    </div>
    <div class="piePipe-wrapper piePipe-check">
      <img src="https://portfoliowaterfall.pbds.dev/assets/img/PF_RetirementCheck_v01.svg" class="piePipe" alt="Retirement Check"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

.piePipe-container .piePipe-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.33);
  height: 13.9356%;
  background: orange;
}

.piePipe-container .piePipe-wrapper.piePipe-lastPipe {
  height: 21.68%;
  background: blue;
}

.piePipe-container .piePipe-wrapper.piePipe-check {
  height: 18.576%;
  background: yellow;
}

.piePipe-container .piePipe-wrapper img.piePipe {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: right top;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, I come up with the following solution. I am using SCSS instead of CSS so you will see the nesting syntax in my [codepen](https://codepen.io/cheukfungtse/pen/KKNjQPO?editors=1100)

1. For the staggering stuff. You can select each of the child under `pipeContainer` using `&` and `nth-child(<number>)`
2. For adding padding between the second last child, `nth-last-child` can be used as this count child from the last.

Comment: Thanks dude! This is awesome. I appreciate you taking the time to whip up a codepen for me. Any ideas on how I would make the parent wrapper adapt to the width of all the images inside it so I can center it, while the images remain floated to the right?

Comment: "make the parent wrapper adapt to the width of all the images inside it", you mean you wanna show the full image?